# Sum on case expression when working with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum, case

I'm looking to create a view which will output the data in the following format

```
AgedPeriod   BillValue  Status
<1            35000     Outstanding 
1-3           23386     Outstanding 
3-6           5000      Outstanding
```

I can use the code below to SUM each case statement into a new column and I could name the column headings after the AgedPeriod listed above but even though the `SUMS` are right the format is wrong I would like to have the code below nested in another CASE statement that does not have to be GROUPED by `b.BILL_DATE` as grouping with the bill date defeats the purpose of my SUM. All attempts as using another CASE statement always bring the `b.BILL_DATE` out of the `SUM` and into the WHEN condition requiring it to be grouped.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN (b.BILL_DATE <= GetDate() 
             AND b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(mm,-1, GetDate())) 
        THEN b.OUTSTANDING END),
SUM(CASE WHEN (b.BILL_DATE <= DateAdd(mm,-1, GetDate()) 
              AND b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(mm,-3, GetDate())) 
         THEN b.OUTSTANDING END),
SUM(CASE WHEN (b.BILL_DATE <= DateAdd(mm,-3, GetDate()) 
              AND b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(mm,-6, GetDate())) 
         THEN b.OUTSTANDING END) 
FROM  dbo.Tables
```

I understand this may not be achievable with the route that I have taken at present but is there be any other way I can `SUM` the outstanding amount on each time period? I can deal with the status column (no advice needed there)

I have added a table and some sample data and left a query to show how I would want the data split up but it would want it to be formatted as above (in a column)

[Example on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e364d/1)

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms? (E.g DateAdd and GetDate are product specific.)

Comment: if you can provide us with sample data, table definitions and expected result with more detail then we will be able to help better

Comment: @jarlh It's SSMS and T-SQL

Comment: @Jeremy C I've tried to simplify this so it didn't get confusing. The expected result would be as above. I'll add a link in the main post to help provide additional detail. Thanks

Comment: If the three age periods are fixed then you can use UNION instead.

Comment: @A.Salman It is going to be a fairly substantial return in data and I have only give you a snippet of the date ranges as they go back 3 years (for every 3 month period). That would make a UNION for each row.. I'll see what it looks like but not sure it's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `group by` rather than conditional aggregation.  The query you want is something like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month,-1, GetDate())
             THEN '<1'
             WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month, -3, GetDate())
             THEN '1-3'
             WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month, -6, GetDate())
             THEN '3-6'
             ELSE '6+'
        END) as AgedPeriod,
       SUM(Outstanding)
FROM dbo.Tables b
WHERE b.BILL_DATE <= GetDate()
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month,-1, GetDate())
               THEN '<1'
               WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month, -3, GetDate())
               THEN '1-3'
               WHEN b.BILL_DATE >= DateAdd(month, -6, GetDate())
               THEN '3-6'
               ELSE '6+'
          END);
```

Notes:

- The groups are defined by a `CASE` statement.  Because this is evaluated in order, you can simplify the logic.
- The common condition `b.BILL_DATE <= GetDate()` is moved to the `WHERE` clause.
- I added an extra condition for longer than six months.  It seems like you wouldn't want to ignore these.
- I don't know what the final column is supposed to be.

Comment: I can see where you were going with this but even though it splits the GROUP BY on BILL_DATE I get the error

Column 'BILL.BILL_DATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. 

I was expecting different. I'll add a link in the main post to help provide additional detail. Thanks

Comment: After implementing both ways I found this one the best Gordon. I missed the alias typo. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a `subquery` or `CTE` to perform the case when statement and then join back to the base table to get the **sum** for the outstanding column like this:

```
SELECT a.AgedPeriod
    ,sum(t1.Outstanding) BillValue
    ,a.[Status]
FROM dbo.Bill t1
JOIN (
    SELECT (
            CASE 
                WHEN b.BILLDATE >= DateAdd(month, - 1, GetDate())
                    THEN '<1'
                WHEN b.BILLDATE >= DateAdd(month, - 3, GetDate())
                    THEN '1-3'
                WHEN b.BILLDATE >= DateAdd(month, - 6, GetDate())
                    THEN '3-6'
                ELSE '6+'
                END
            ) AS AgedPeriod
        ,b.[ID]
        ,'Outstanding' [Status]
    FROM dbo.Bill b
    WHERE b.BILLDATE <= GetDate()
    ) a ON a.[ID] = t1.[ID]
GROUP BY a.AgedPeriod
    ,a.[Status]
```

Hope this helps! Here is a SQL Fiddle Demo for this:

[SQL Fiddle Solution Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e364d/7/0)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I think. Your SQL Fiddle shapes up well and the early re-write looks good. Thanks @Nepali Rookie